# Artifactory plugin calling another plugin

Tags: plugins, artifactory

Is there a way to call another artifactory plugin from an artifactory plugin?

We use artifactory user plugins a lot in our company and it works fine but sometime we could see the need to call directly another plugin instead of copying the code around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is reusing logic between plugins, you can encapsulate this logic in Java classes and import them in your plugins. You can package the reusable code in a java archive (jar) and place it as a library under the `${ARTIFACTORY_HOME}/etc/plugins/lib` directory.